# Connection on direct sum of vector bundles written as a matrix

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, connections

I am trying to solve the following problem:
[image]

I have to admit I am completly stuck and don't even know where to start. The notes I am reading introduce $E_{1}\oplus E_{1}$ rather briefly. I had a look at Lee's books and I found a short discussion about the direct sum of two vector bundles. I think I am fine with $E_{1}\oplus E_{1}$ being a vector bundle and that a connection on $E_{1}\oplus E_{1}$ can be defined by $\nabla:=\nabla_{1}\oplus\nabla_{2}$. What puzzles me is the matrix representation of a connection. We never talked about anything like a correspondence between connections and matrices. Furthermore forms are introduced in the next chapter. Yet two entries are forms. I guess, since they are 1-forms, they are "only" linear maps.

I would really appreciate some tips or source where I can look it up or that explains this "correspondence" so that I can solve the problem myself.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ are connections on $E$, then their difference $\nabla - \nabla'$ is an "endomorphism-valued $1$-form" $B \in \Omega^1(M,\mathrm{End}(E))$. If $E=E_1 \oplus E_2$ then we can define the connection $\nabla^1$ by

$$ \nabla^1_X(s_1) = \mathrm{pr}_1 \nabla_X(s_1) $$

for a (local) section $s_1$ of $E_1$, where $\mathrm{pr}_1 \colon E \to E_1$ is the projection defined by the direct sum. You can do the same for $\nabla^2$. Then $\nabla-\nabla^1-\nabla^2$ is an endomorphism-valued $1$-form on $E$, and taking a look at the definition you see that

$$ \tilde{A}_X(s_1) = \mathrm{pr}_2 \nabla_X(s_1) .$$

Comment: I am afraid I am still confused. According to my notes $\nabla-\nabla^{1} -\nabla^{2}\in\Gamma(Hom(TM,End(E_{1}\oplus E_{2})))$. Let $p\in M$. Then $\nabla-\nabla^{1} -\nabla^{2}$ eats a tangent vector $X_{q}$ and spits out an element of $End(E)$. Is that why you say it is End(E)-valued one-form? I sort of see how the construction of $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ works, but I still don't see how to come up with the matrix.

Comment: Organizing $\nabla^1,A,\tilde{A},\nabla^2$ into a matrix is just a way to keep track of which connection/homomorphism is defined on $E_1$ vs $E_2$ and which takes values on $E_1$ vs $E_2$. Not much needs to go into the fact that $\nabla$ can be decomposed into four parts $E_1 \to E_1,E_1 \to E_2,$ etc. But you should be mindful of the fact that the "diagonal components" will be connections and the "off-diagonal components" will be tensorial, i.e. $A(fs)=fA(s)$ for a smooth function $f$.